# How to use PHP drawing functions with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, http-headers

I'm trying to use PHP shape drawing functions with the Laravel framework but I am having some trouble.

So, I just to test it out, basically just copied the example from php.net and used it in a closure and a test route.

```
Route::get('maptest', function()
{
$image = imagecreatetruecolor(200, 200);
$red = imagecolorallocate($image, 227, 32, 32);

imagefilledrectangle($image, 100, 80, 50, 25, $red);

header('Content-Type: image/png');

imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
});
```

doing it this way works fine.

the problem is when I throw a `Controller` and a `View` into the mix. When I set the headers and what not and create a `Response`, I get a little broken picture icon in the top left corner of the window and nothing on the page loads at all.

this is how I am setting the headers.
(I know this is posted everywhere, but none of the solutions I could find seemed to work for me.)

```
public function show($id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);

    $view = View::make('profile/home', ['user' => $user]);

    $response = Response::make($view, 200);
    $response->header('Content-type', 'image/png');

    return $response;
}
```

So the result of the above code (inside my controller) gives me a little broken picture icon in top left corner of window.

Comment: Why are you setting the `Content-type` to `image/png` when you're not even outputting an image?

Comment: i am, that's happening in the profile/home View

Comment: You're not. You're outputting HTML to the browser. Not an image file. What happens if you comment out the line where you set the `Content-type` header? Do you see an HTML page?

Comment: yes i do see HTML if i comment that out. i guess i'm asking where am i supposed to set the header for the image then, because if i don't set the header the imagepng() function (on the view) just outputs a bunch of random symbols.

Comment: Don't call `imagejpeg()` in your view. Call it somewhere else (e.g. your controller), and capture the output using output buffer, and encode it in base64. From there, you can just use the `img` HTML tag with the base64 string as the source of the image. Another solution would be to have another controller that output just the image, and then have your `img` tag points to that controller.

Comment: @BradyLatsha do you mind posting your working code?